# Haskell error when implementing Tower of Hanoi

Tags: haskell, towers-of-hanoi

I am trying to implement a recursive function for Tower of Hanoi.

The algorithm is:

```
Move n−1 disks from peg AA to peg C using peg B as intermediate storage.

Move the nth disk from peg A to peg B,

Move n−1 disks from peg C to peg BB using peg A as intermediate storage.
```

Eample:

```
hanoi 2 "a" "b" "c" =
[("a","c"), ("a","b"), ("c","b")]
```

This is my implementation

```
hanoi :: Integer -> Peg -> Peg -> Peg -> [Move] 

hanoi x "a" "b" "c" 
    | x <= 0    = []
    | x == 1    = [("a", "b")]
    | otherwise = (hanoi (x-1) "a" "c" "b") ++ [("a", "b")] ++ (hanoi (x-1) "c" "b" "a")
```

However I got an error said `there is un-exhausted pattern`.
What does it mean an how can I solve it?

Comment: arguments do not need to be enclosed in quotes. Here, they even shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments to Haskell functions are actually patterns that the supplied values are matched against.

`a` is an irrefutable pattern that always succeeds by matching up the variable `a` with the supplied value, whether `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"` or something else entirely.

`"a"` is also a pattern, but it will *only* succeed when matched up with a *matching* value, `"a"`:

```
~> let f "a" = 1
f :: Num a => [Char] -> a

~> f "a"
1
it :: Num a => a

~> f "c"
*** Exception: <interactive>:3:5-13: Non-exhaustive patterns in function f
```

So, do not enclose your arguments in quotes when defining functions, if you want them to be interpreted as variable patterns.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is really helpful.